# Ruby on Rails: Create a new record that belongs to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `users`, who have `posts`.

I want to create a new post for user #1. I want to do this using syntax similar to Option #2, where its chained to the original user selection. Is this possible?

Option 1 (I know how to do this):

```
user = User.find(1)
post = Post.create(content: "foobar content", user: user)
```

Option 2 (is this possible?):

```
User.find(1).new_post(content: "foobar content")
```

Comment: Yes, [this could help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`build`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/build) method:

```
user = User.find(1).posts.build(content: "post content")
```

In the case of a `has_one` relationship, invoke the [`build_association`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/build_association) method:

```
user = User.find(1).build_profile(content: "profile content")
```

In either event, a new child object is initialized and associated to the parent `User`, *however*, you'll need to `save` your `User` instance in order to preserve the association:

```
user.save
```

**Alternatively**, the same associations can be created via the [`create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/create) and [`create_association`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/create_association) methods:

```
User.find(1).posts.create(content: "post content")
User.find(1).create_profile(content: "profile content")
```

Neither call requires that the parent be saved – the associated child is created and saved at the instant that the respective creation method is called.

**An important note**: *both the `create` and `create_association` methods are deprecated in Rails 4*.

Comment: Also it could be creation instead of initializing. I guess he should know that this should be saved.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys. Will accept when timer is up. Also maybe you have insight into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944676/rails-convention-for-a-users-groups-and-pages-with-profile-picture-polymorphi

Comment: @zishe, creation methods are deprecated in Rails 4, but I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: @DonnyP, no need to cross-post. If someone has an answer to your other questions, they'll post. If this answer has helped resolve your issue, please consider [upvoting/accepting it as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @zeantsoi thanks, didn't know about that, `guides.rubyonrails` has no info about that, while it's deprecated since 3.1 version.

Comment: @zeantsoi - thanks, the only reason I didn't accept immediately was because the timer hadn't run up. And I cross posted since often I'll answer a question but not see tangential questions.